What tool to use? For Broken sp
2015 Kia optima so one the spark plugs snapped. The bottom half of the spark plug is stuck inside. What do I use? To get it out, which tool?? Exactly For this sedan
The bottom half is stuck

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does this answer your question? What is the proper way to extract a broken sparkplug?

Without the image of the other part of the spark plug it is difficult to suggest how hard it will be to remove the remaining part.
I would first look at turning the engine to  suitable point so I could used compressed air to pressurise that particular cylinder. This will be to help prevent swarf descending into the combustion chamber, but it will still be a risk.
Then I would look at trying to remove the centre portion of the old spark plug, that does depend on where it broke. If it is just "sitting" there then wobbling it with increased pressure behind may cause it to pop out.
With the centre part removed the threaded body could be removed by one of those left hand threaded removers that are common.
If that threaded portion is corroded in place then some soaking with penetrants may be needed - there are products (not WD40) which are good at penetrating - a quick option is often ATF auto gearbox oil as that is known to find any minor "crack" to produce a leak. More seriously there are several sources that suggest ATF with other additions makes a good pentrant.

The bottom part tred of the spark plug in in ther I wanna say  it look like

It may be worth applying penetrating oil to the thread anyway, to make removal easier.
